# Creating a custom NSWindow interface

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow, nscolor

I am trying to create an instance of `NSWindow` that has a style similar to that of Pixelmator, pictured below:

http://ideaorange.com/files/2010/12/pixelmato-sprinklebig.jpg&gt;">

Basically, I would like to know how to create a window similar to that style, with the black title bar. Would I have to write the entire window out in code? Or is it possible to do in interface builder? Much appreciated.

Comment: If you don't use the standard Cocoa windows, you have to do everything yourself. That means doing your own drawing, dragging, resizing, window controls, everything. You may be able to find some custom code out there to get started.

Answer (score 1):

[The HUD appearance](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSHUDWindowMask) is what you're looking for. Note, however, that it only applies to panels (like Pixelmator's palettes), not standard windows (such as document windows). It also does not apply to controls, such as buttons; Pixelmator's are undoubtedly custom.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial is a good place to start: http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/drawing-custom-window-on-mac-os-x.html

There's a load of work involved in developing your own windows so be sure you're up for the challenge.

And another note, be sure to review your code against Apple's AppStore policies, as some of the window theming examples out on the web do use private API's which Apple won't approve for distribution through the app store.

Comment: Also, checkout the source of frameworks like [BWToolkit](http://brandonwalkin.com/bwtoolkit/), you'll learn loads about how to create custom controls and _hack_ the Cocoa GUI